how to add a new text input while the web page is running in streamlit
When I run the code in the browser and select "others" in the 'topic' key.
I want a new text input below it.
import streamlit as st
import emailing


st.session_state['topic'] = None

with st.form(key='email'):
    user_email = st.text_input('Enter your email:', key='email')
    about = st.selectbox('what do you wanna discuss', options=('job', 'projects', 'salary', 'other'),
                         key='topic')

    if about == 'other':
        other_about = st.text_input('what do you wanna discuss about')

    message = st.text_area('message', key='message')
    button = st.form_submit_button('submit')

    string = f"""\
subject: NEW ONE

from {user_email}
TOPIC: {about}
{message}
"""
    if button:
        emailing.send(string)
        st.info('success')


I tried running a 'if' statement and asked chatgpt but it isn't effective.
When I choose "others" the new text input won't appear

Try: if about == 'other':         other_about = st.empty() first?

I would remove the email and about inputs from the form. The if about == "other": was never triggered correctly. Also, I would remove the st.session_state['topic'] = None line to avoid resetting the selectbox after every interaction with a widget.
import streamlit as st

user_email = st.text_input("Enter your email:", key="email")
about = st.selectbox(
    "what do you wanna discuss",
    options=("job", "projects", "salary", "other"),
    key="topic",
)

if about == "other":
    other_about = st.text_input("what do you wanna discuss about")

with st.form(key="email"):
    message = st.text_area("message", key="message")
    button = st.form_submit_button("submit")

    string = f"""\
subject: NEW ONE

from {user_email}
TOPIC: {about}
{message}
"""
    if button:
        st.write(f"EMAIL TO SEND:{string}")
        st.info("success")

It gives:


it works! thank you. But why didn't it work when I used it in the st.form?? Also in your code, did it rerun the entire code after an input was given?(I'm a beginner, so I can't understand it well )
